# xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar with gem using HTTParty and multi_xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, encoding, rubygems

I'm getting this error when using a gem that depends on HTTParty and multi_xml:

```
MultiXml::ParseError: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/multi_xml-0.5.5/lib/multi_xml/parsers/nokogiri.rb:15:in `parse'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/multi_xml-0.5.5/lib/multi_xml.rb:138:in `parse'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/parser.rb:111:in `xml'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/parser.rb:140:in `parse_supported_format'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/parser.rb:102:in `parse'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/parser.rb:66:in `call'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:241:in `parse_response'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:211:in `block in handle_response'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/response.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/response.rb:18:in `parsed_response'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/response.rb:51:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/commission_junction-1.5.0/lib/commission_junction.rb:146:in `link_search'
```

Seems this is an encoding issue or due to some character one of the libraries doesn't like.

The gem I'm using is commission_junction. To fix this issue, maybe I need to fork it and specify some encoding option? I'm digging through the code which is [here](https://github.com/aevernon/commission_junction/blob/master/lib/commission_junction.rb).

I tried using the latest commission_junction and HTTParty gems...no help.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the commission_junction gem. I've released version 1.7.0, which includes Chad Johnson's fix of using the "ox" gem.

Comment: Nice :) Happy to help. Thanks for the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by simply adding the "ox" gem (an XML parser) to the Gemfile for my project.